# Entity Framework Code First AddOrUpdate with complex key having enum

Tags: c#, entity-framework, enums

```
public class User
    {

     //... rest of the properties

     [Index("IX_Unique",1,IsUnique = true)]
     public int DepartmentId {get; set;}

     [Index("IX_Unique",2,IsUnique = true)]
     public EmployementType EmployementType {get; set;}

   }
 public enum EmployementType 
    {
        Contract=1,
        FullTime,
        PartTime,
    }
```

using EF Code first Seed,when I run the below line, it is always try to do **INSERT**, which will fail from second attempt, because first attempt will already inserted those records

```
context.Users.AddOrUpdate(p => new { p.DepartmentId, p.EmployementType }, users.ToArray());
```

same kind of complex key check on AddOrUpdate works for other seeds, but those don't have **enum** types in complex key

How can I make this work with out replacing **enum** with integer type

I am using EF 6.1.3, C# 4.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to identify the problem and fix it. (But could not really understand the insight problem in it)

What I was doing is (**this one was failing** and was always doing inserts instead of update).

```
var demoDepartment = context.Department.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals("HR", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))

            demoDepartment.Users.Add(new User()
            {
                DepartmentId = demoDepartment.Id,
                Name="John",
                // All properties
                IsActive = true
            });

          demoDepartment.Users.Add(new User()
            {
                DepartmentId = demoDepartment.Id,
                Name="Smith",
                // All properties
                IsActive = true
            });
```

context.Users.AddOrUpdate(p => new { p.DepartmentId, p.EmployementType }, demoDepartment.Users.ToArray());

**Fix is**

```
List<User> users = new List<User>();
    var demoDepartment = context.Department.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals("HR", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))

                users.Add(new User()
                {
                    DepartmentId = demoDepartment.Id,
                    Name="John",
                    // All properties
                    IsActive = true
                });

              users.Add(new User()
                {
                    DepartmentId = demoDepartment.Id,
                    Name="Smith",
                    // All properties
                    IsActive = true
                });

context.Users.AddOrUpdate(p => new { p.DepartmentId, p.EmployementType }, users.ToArray());
```

Though I got the seeding working, I still am interested to find out why `Department.Users.ToArray()` did not work but `List<Users>.ToArray()` worked. If any one can through some light on this, it would be a great help.